# Please can anyone help me with this to make a random numbers show in input value?

Tags: javascript

Please can someone tell me what to do on this?

I have input text and I want a random number to change once I click the button but is not working with the input it only work if I use `<p id="random"></p>` tag or a `div` to call the ID. Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var number = Math.random();
    document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = number;
}

<button onclick="myFunction()">change</button>
<input type="text" value="" id="random">`
```

Answer (score 3):

change it to value. You dont want to add to the html of the input only the value it is displaying

```
function myFunction() {
    var number = Math.random();
    document.getElementById("random").value = number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Input's don't show the `innerHTML`. Use `.value`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var number = Math.random();
    document.getElementById("random").value = number;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">change</button>
<input type="text" value="" id="random">
```

Comment: Please i need the input to clear the text inside after i submitted it,

Comment: @PeterValentine i'm not sure what you mean? there isn't a form here.

Comment: How can i combine this tow script function 
function myFunction() {
    var number = Math.random();
    document.getElementById("demo").value = number;
}

myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

I want it to reset for after i click

Comment: @PeterValentine that is a separate question. please ask a new one.